# Disable uipopover tap gesture recognizer

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipopover

I know that UIpopover will be dismissed automatically when you tap outside of the popover.

I need to disable tap recognizer, because I have 4 buttons each of which present popover and when you tap another button another popover must be shown.

When I tap another button first popover is disappearing (I can handle it programmatically) but second button's function is not calling because tap is already "consumed".

I tried to remove tap gesture recognizer from popover but no success.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could assign the buttons to the popover presentation controller's `passthroughViews` array to allow interaction while the popover is visible.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipopoverpresentationcontroller/1622312-passthroughviews?changes=_4